# Cannot handle right syntax for Mysql multiple else if query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Here is the query:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
(
    IF t1.sms_phone IS NOT NULL THEN t1.sms_phone
    ELSE IF t1.insuringPhone IS NOT NULL THEN t1.insuringPhone
    ELSE IF t1.person_id IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT person_contact.value FROM person_contact where person_contact.person_id = t1.person_id AND person_contact.contact_id = 2 ORDER BY person_contact.last_change DESC LIMIT 1) END IF) as phone
FROM test_table as t1
WHERE id = 187842
```

Also tried with `CASE` without success:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
(
    CASE
    WHEN t1.sms_phone IS NOT NULL THEN t1.sms_phone
    WHEN t1.insuringPhone IS NOT NULL THEN t1.insuringPhone
    WHEN t1.person_id IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT person_contact.value FROM person_contact where person_contact.person_id = t1.person_id AND person_contact.contact_id = 2 ORDER BY person_contact.last_change DESC LIMIT 1)
) as phone
FROM test_table as t1
WHERE id = 187842
```

Comment: IF statement cannot be used in a query - it is designed for to be used in compound statements only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html) which returns the first non-null argument.

```
SELECT t1.id, COALESCE(t1.sms_phone, t1.insuringPhone, ...)
```

For person_id an other solution seems better: maybe if a limited COALESCE returns NULL,
query further.

Comment: Looks OK, but how to get result from `COALESCE` like this `if COALESCE(NULL, NULL, value) IS NOT NULL THEN .. return this .. else query further`

Comment: The last, third argument could be the subquery (never tried), without check on person_id being null. Not sure this answer works, but COALESCE i.o. null checks seems appropriate.